# how to pass json in jQuery $.ajax method?

Tags: jquery, json

I have following json data which I want to pass it to server using $.ajax. I tried many times, nothing returned, which is suppose to return another json object. Please help

```
$(function() {
        var parameters = {
            "firstName": "Saumil",
            "lastName": "Jhaveri",
            "email": "test@test.com",
            "address": "650+Townsend+St,+St.+325",
            "city": "San+Francisco",
            "state": "California",
            "zipCode": "94103",
            "country": "United+States",
            "phone": "312&375&1884",
            "industry": "Accounting",
            "organization": "Citrix",
            "jobTitle": "Software+Engineer",
            "purchasingTimeFrame": "1&3+months",
            "roleInPurchaseProcess": "Decision+Maker",
            "numberOfEmployees": "1&20",
            "questionsAndComments": "No+Comments!",
            "responses": [{
                "questionKey": 152,
                "responseText": "Fantastic!"
            }, {
                "questionKey": 151,
                "answerKey": 152
             }]
            };
          var jsonData=$.toJSON(parameters);  
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://api.citrixonline.com/G2W/rest/organizers/2934047/webinars/439546160/registrants?oauth_token=57f9454c6aecec65adef1ca66cbfde02",
        data: jsonData,
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                $('#key').html(data.registrantKey);
                $('#url').html(data.joinUrl);
            }
        });
    });
```

Here's the div that I want to display returned data.

```
<div id="key"></div>
<div id="url"></div>
```

I have no control on the url that I send data to, but it is says I'll receive response something as follows:

```
     HTTP/1.1 201 OK
 Content-Type: application/json
 {
 "registrantKey":5678,
 "joinUrl":"https://www1.gotomeeting.com/join/123456789/5678"
 }
```

Comment: You said that nothing is returned, but you haven't told us what you've done to make sure that the server-side code correctly reads your JSON.

Comment: Is `$.toJSON` a plugin you are including? Because jQuery does not have that method.

Comment: @Jasper, then how to convert it into json? Shoud I use that parameters directly in $.ajax()?

Comment: Well you can use `$.toJSON` if you include the plugin after you include the jQuery core and before you try to run `$.toJSON`: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/. `JSON.stringify` is the browser implementation but it's not supported in all browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$.toJSON` method will return a string formatted as JSON. This string can be the value of a `POSt` variable if you give it a key:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://api.citrixonline.com/G2W/rest/organizers/2934047/webinars/439546160/registrants?oauth_token=57f9454c6aecec65adef1ca66cbfde02",
    data: 'jsonData=' + jsonData,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#key').html(data.registrantKey);
            $('#url').html(data.joinUrl);
        }
    });
```

I'm assuming that the `$.toJSON` method you are using is part of this plugin: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/

Comment: I did as you suggested. I also added an alert("test") in success function, but no message pop up.

Comment: Add error reporting to your ajax call with an `error` callback: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax. Then you will know why the JS is failing. I have no idea what your server-side code is doing so I can't help much more.

Comment: You are right. I added error:function(result){alert(result.ErrorMessage);} It returns undefined. Do you have an idea?

Comment: You will get more meaningful information using this: `error : function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.log(jqXHR); console.log(textStatus); console.log(errorThrown);}`. The important part is that the `error` function is passed three arguments, the second and third ones will help you troubleshoot your problem.